# Why isn't my picture loading from my static folder?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working with the Django framework and am having some problems with referencing the source of an image from my HTML page. I continuously get this error in my terminal

```
Not Found: /bread.jpg
"GET /bread.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2445
```

although the last 4 digit string is different with every attempt I make to fix it.

My project (YeOldeShoppe) has an app (Shoppe) and is laid out like this

```
YeOldeShoppe 
  Shoppe
    migrations
    templates
      index.html
    urls.py
    views.py
  YeOldeShoppe
    static
      bread.jpg
    settings.py
    urls.py
  manage.py
```

The code I'm having an issue with is in my index.html

```
{% load static %}
...
<div style="width: 25%; display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
    <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}bread.jpg" alt="Great Value Bread"/>
    <h2>Bread</h2>
    <h5>$0.99</h5>
</div>
```

In my settings.py I've already set STATIC_URL

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my urls.py of Shoppe I tried to add it to urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

So far, I've tried to have the static folder be in the root directory of YeOldeShoppe
(eg. with manage.py), I've tried it in the YeOldeShoppe subdir (with settings.py) and in
my Shoppe subdir (with views.py). I tried having the both templates dir with the static dir
in the root (with manage.py), and I tried to use the command python manage.py collectstatic. I've also tried a variation of using "{{STATIC_URL}}bread.jpg" and "{% static "bread.jpg"%}".

Comment: Try `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`

Comment: @mplungjan tried that, same error

Comment: Double check the static path, you might also have to do `{% static '/bread.jpg/' %}` with the leading forward-slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static "bread.jpg"%}" alt="Great Value Bread"/>
```

try adding these to the settings.py and urls.py:

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [...
                 (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
                 ...
                 ],
        ...
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Tried that, still just getting the alt text and the 404 error in my terminal.

Comment: see edited answer and let me know how that goes, make sure that those directories are specified (assuming your using the built-in django debug server)

Comment: worked perfectly. Fantastic.